# How to make center_changed listener in Google Map API v3 only fire once?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am currently using 'center_changed',function() as a listener to get the lat and lng of the map centre and then subsequently calling a reverse geocode method to convert the lat and lng into an address. However, since center_changed is firing more than once when the map is being dragged, i get a prompt message "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" from my reverse geocode method. Is there a way to make the centre_changed listener only fire once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the addLlistenerOnce method.

[events description in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapsEventListener)